# Prometheus / Grafana highest value and time

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Is it possible in grafana with a prometheus backend to determine the highest value recorded for the lifetime of a data set, and if so, determine the time that the value occurred?

For example, I'm using `site_logged_in` as the query in a Singlestat panel to get the current number of logged in users, along with a nice graph of recent activity over the past hour.  Wrapping that in a `max()` seems to do nothing, and a `max_over_time(site_logged_in[1y])` gives me a far too low number.

The value is a single gauge value coming from the endpoint like so

```
# HELP site_logged_in Logged In Members
# TYPE site_logged_in gauge
site_logged_in 583
```

Is something like determining highest values even a realistic use case for prometheus?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`max_over_time(site_logged_in[1y])` is the max over the past year, however this presumes that you have a year worth of data to work from.

Comment: Does that conflict at all with grafana's resolution / min step / time range features? I've had spikes over 500, but max_over_time is returning about 460.  We implemented prometheus 4 months ago, would setting the range higher than the available data throw it off?

Comment: Those only affect graphs, and would make little difference for a range this long anyway. Most likely your retention period is less than a year, so you're only have more recent data.

Comment: Yup, looks like I screwed something up in the config.  It was keeping 15 days. It's now set to 150 days, close enough for what we're going for.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The highest value over the specified time range can be obtained with [max_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#max_over_time) function. For example, the following value would return the maximum value for `site_logged_in` metric over the last year:

```
max_over_time(site_logged_in[1y])
```

Unfortunately Prometheus doesn't provide the function for returning the timestamp for the maximum value. If you need to obtain the timestamp for the maximum value, then you can use [tmax_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#tmax_over_time) function from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). For example, the following MetricsQL query returns the timestamp in seconds for the maximum value of `site_logged_in` metric over the last year:

```
tmax_over_time(site_logged_in[1y])
```